# Right animation jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have four blocks with pictures  and I need to animate them: When you make mouse over block it goes down;
when you take it away it goes up .Now I have the problem that I'm moving mouse very fast blocks starts queueing my actions and after some times it seems like they move without me
[image: my blocks-pictures]

JS code:

```
$('.blocks').hover( up, down );
    function up() {
            $(this)
            .animate ({
                top: '+=400px'}, 1000);
    }

function down() {
    $(this).delay(300)
        .animate ({
            top: '-=400px'}, 800);
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('.blocks').hover( up, down );

function up() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            top: '+=400px'
        }, 1000);
}

function down() {
        $(this).stop().delay(300).animate({
            top: '-=400px'
        }, 800);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop your animation before queuing a new animation to avoid this problem. You can find more details at http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

> It is pretty common when using jQuery's .animate() function that it is triggered by a mouseEnter or hover event. That's all well and good, but it means that we need account for those events being triggered multiple times.

**Solution:**
Use the jQuery stop() function [docs](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Example:

```
$('.blocks').hover( up, down );

function up() {
    $(this).stop().animate ({ top: '+=400px' }, 1000);
}

function down() {
    $(this).stop().delay(300).animate ({ top: '-=400px'}, 800);
}
```

Chris Coyier has written a good article about how to deal with this. 
http://css-tricks.com/full-jquery-animations/

Comment: Thanks for the useful links, but  i still don't get how using` jQuery stop() function` make blocks it move right , cause when you stop the animation The block starts behaving itself strange moving not only up and down for 400px,but twice up for 800px for example.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, if you make a jsfiddle with your example I'll take a look at it for you. @user2950593